# Can distribution function of $f$ be expressed as triangle inequality form?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $w_f$ be a distribution function of $f$ on $E\in\Bbb{R^n}$,$$w_f(\alpha) := \mu\left(\{\mathbf{x}\in E ~|~ f(\mathbf{x} \gt \alpha\}\right)$$

---

From triangle inequality, $$|f| \le |f-f_k|+|f_k|.$$

We can get the following inequality from the above; $$w_{|f|} \le w_{|f-f_k|}+w_{|f_k|}.$$

---

By drawing some examples on $\Bbb{R^2}$ domain, I understood, for $f \le g$, $$w_f \le w_g.$$

So, for $|f| \le |f-f_k|+|f_k|$, I can get
$$w_{|f|} \le w_{|f-f_k|+|f_k|}.$$

However, I cannot proceed more. Please give me some ways.

Comment: This is obviously false, consider the constant functions $f=4$ and $f_k=2$ for $\alpha=3$. What is true however is that $w_{f+g}(a+b)\leqslant w_f(a)+w_g(b)$ for every $f$, $g$, $a$, $b$.

Comment: @Did Ah.. Then, this solution of [5.10][link] is false?  


  [link]: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math605/solutions6.pdf